# Trying to Simply Access Array in Papaparse

Tags: javascript, arrays, papaparse

I'm trying to simply access an array in Papaparse - and then spit out elements of that array either by header name or just by array address (1,1) etc.

However, I can't even get the data to load correctly. The count of lines shows up correctly at 258, but the whole thing reads[object Object], [object Object], [object Object] ...etc

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="PapaParse/papaparse.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var results;
    var data;
    var file = "datapipe.csv";

    Papa.parse(file, {
      download: true,
      header: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      delimiter: "|",
      complete: function(results) {
        data = results;
        console.log("Remote file parsed!", results);
        //document.write(results.data["1"][0] );
        document.write(results.data );
      }
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use console.log to show this data and open browser console to look

Comment: I'm going to need to write that data anyway for what I'm doing next

Comment: The question is what type of data your datapipe.csv file contains? Json objects?

Comment: `results.data` is an object/array, so when you try to write it to the document it says "[object Object]" - you need something like results.data[0] to get the first element...

Comment: results.data[0]  returns [object Object]

Comment: That's the first row. You need to specify a field name to get to an actual value.

Comment: What's the syntax on that?

Comment: File is loading fine - field names are showing up in results.meta - just having this format problem. I need to access field names and row number to make a loop

Comment: Nvm, figured it out console.log(results.data[1]["NAME"]);